# create list from object array javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, html-lists

I have a object array that is built from user input forms and I want them to output to HTML using lists but not sure how this is done. Ive heard of using innerHTML but read that it isn't the best way to do this due to performance. Here is my code.

**JavaScript**

```js
var taskList = {
  name: []
}

function saveTask(e) {

  var task = document.getElementById("AddForm").value;
  if (task) {
    addToArray(task);
  }

  e.preventDefault();

}

function addToArray(task) {
  taskList.name.push(task);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  console.log(taskList);
}

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener('submit', saveTask);
```

I want to save the lists here in HTML

```
 <ul id="items"></ul>
```

Comment: Please show [minimal, complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: @lightstalker89 better click `<>` and provide a stack snippet

Comment: Hey yes sorry, here is a jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/DDjid/dhj5r38p/

Comment: Also I have an understanding of 'for' loops, just haven't used it with list groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, you just want to add each pushed element to the `ul`, as a `li`.
I think this modification should be enough:

```
function addToArray(task){
  taskList.name.push(task);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  var list = document.getElementById('items');
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.innerHTML = task;
  list.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for that!